# Calling a function from the master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, master-pages

masterpage.master

code

```
protected void btnAddLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //how can call btnSendMessage_Click
}
```

---

page1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="page1.aspx.cs"  Inherits="page1"%>
```

Code

```
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //how call btnAddLink_Click
}
```

how can call `btnAddLink_Click` in page1.aspx

how can call `btnSendMessage_Click` in masterpage.master

Comment: Also, you can't have C# in the ASPX if there is a CodeFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of he ASPX, just below the @Page tag, add a <%@MasterType... tag.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="page1"%>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masterpage.master" %>
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  Master.btnAddLink_Click(Nothing,Nothing); }
```

Comment: Yuck is correct, you shouldn't be calling code in the page FROM the master.  But calling master code from the page should be OK.

Comment: please write a example i does not understand